# Parse.User.current(), globals etc

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to Express and Parse.  I am trying to make a simple modification to the Anyimg cloud tutorial.  I would like to display the default home page only if the user is authenticated.  If I use Parse.User.authenticated(), I get:

The error was TypeError: Object function (){e.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'authenticated'
    at app.js:33:18
    at main.js:1:1

Parse.User.current() compiles with no error, but the code does not work.  What am I missing?  I have tried literally over 60 different options over the last 3 days with no success.

I also tried to declare a GLOBAL from within user.js and that did not work.  I did a require cloud/user from within app.js and that did not help at all.

I hope someone can help.  It appears that Parse tutorials (outside parse.com) from about a year ago break.

On the other hand, I wanted to display the login page (not default) upon logout.  I got it done in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: post your code, it will help understand things better.

Comment: Hi Fosco,  That is exactly the code I had (used a different boolean name though).  However, I was trying to mess with globals and had declared the var at the top of the file/module.

I moved that declaration within the function scope and now it all works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, I already had code that was similar to Fosco's.  However, the var statement was not in the scope of the function as I was trying out o.  I just moved it in and it all works.  Thanks to everyone for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
if (currentUser) {
  // logged in
} else {
  // not logged in
}
```

`Parse.User.current()` returns the current user, or undefined if not logged in.

as seen here: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-current