# Parse.com want to redirect to get from post

Tags: express, parse-platform

I am new to Parse, and am still trying to understand routing.  So please bear with me if this is a dumb question.

Please visit their tutorial:

https://www.anyimg.org/i/QDn6jGX6Lz

On this page, I am trying to add a simple comment.  When I click submit, I want to display the exact same page, but with the comment(s) displayed on the bottom.

Thus far, I can only do some simple redirects upon submit.  But I think I really need to be able to reconstruct a new app.get and redirect to this exact same mount.

I tried something very basic like this (to just display the original get), but even that does not work.

```
app.post('/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;

    // Build the query to find an image by id
    var query = new Parse.Query(Image);
    query.equalTo("objectId", id);
    res.redirect('/i/:id');
});
```

So my questions are:

1. I saw somewhere that you can call an app.get from within app.post, but no matter how much I searched, I could not find that example again.
2. I want to create a comments table in Parse and track it by user name (I realize that I am asking for a mini tutorial here).

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Read up on express til u know how it implements MVC. Then recognize that posting a comment updates model and collection in comments class. So if its wired up the post delegates to collection.add. the collection change will delegate to a refresh on the view.

Comment: This works to redisplay without comments: app.post('/:id', function(req, res) {
        var id = req.params.id;
        res.redirect('/i/' + req.params.id);

Comment: @rowntree Yes, I have done several tutorials (have them all working, even fixed some bugs and sent them back to the authors) on the topics you discuss.  However, most are quite elementary compared to Parse, which is quite a step up from the usual.

Comment: dont know express. I use backbone w/ parse and there, the MVC principals are pretty clear. Look on github for an express/parse proj.

Comment: @rowntree: Parse.com uses only Express (see my tags).  In any case, I was able to get this done.  I have posted detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Proper routing/redirects:  app.post('/:id', function(req, res) { var id = req.params.id; res.redirect('/i/' + req.params.id);  I did not have the "+" originally.
2. I got this mostly done as well

   a. Add a post form in show.ejs.

   b. Make sure that the encoding of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

   I think you need that period at the end of the type.  At least
   Webstorm forced me to add it.  JSON encoding may also work, but I gave up after just a couple of attemts since Webstorm did not "buy" my syntax.

   c. http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/express.html#.bodyParser Like
   this: app.use(express.bodyParser());  You can include just inside the
   post as a local, without the need to break anything else

   d. I then created a new copy of the Image object (Image table in the
   DB), and simply set the comment in one of the columns

   e.  Ideally, you want to set up a comments table, to capture comments
   by user.  But I don't have time to try that.

Note: Make sure the ACL permissions for each user is set correctly in the Image table.  That's what got me.  It allows anonymous users to post.  To prevent this and make everybody log in first, this, see my other post:

[Parse.User.current(), globals etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792000/parse-user-current-globals-etc)